# How to focus the current window with js only?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, focus, html-parsing

I'm writing a bot for myself which is supposed to automatically fill input forms and click buttons on html pages.

The problem I'm facing is that on a certain pages my **script only starts working when I manually click somewhere inside that page**.

I know that my issue is somewhat connected with `window focus` event so I tried to add `window.focus();` to the part of the bot's code that operates on page in question. This does not give any errors and still only works if I manually click the page.

Is there a possibility that window my bot is struggling with is somehow limited to be focused only on user click?

In any case I want to come up with an idea of overcoming it.

**My bot's workflow is a bunch of pieces like this one:**

```
let wait = setInterval(() => {
    if ($("#SOME_INPUT_ID").length) {
        clearInterval(wait);
        // window.focus() <--- does not work, and i still have to click somewhere on the page
        console.log('ready to fill SOME_INPUT_ID');
        change("SOME_INPUT_ID", 'STRING_TO_FILL_SOME_INPUT_ID');

        //...FIND A BUTTON TO PROCEED TO THE NEXT PAGE AND CLICK IT 
    }
}, 1000);
```

**Change function I use to change input values:**

```
const change = (el, value) => {
    var event = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
    var evnt = new Event('focus');
    var evt = new Event('blur');

    if (document.getElementById(el)) {
        var element = document.getElementById(el);

        if (element) {
            element.focus();
            element.dispatchEvent(evnt);
            element.value = value;
            element.dispatchEvent(event);
            element.blur();
            element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What technology are you using to inject these scripts into web pages? You need to find out if (that technology) can switch browser tabs for you.

Comment: @James The script is part of chrome extension so i guess it embeds itself anywhere you want as long as you specify urls in manifest (which i did)